# Keras/tensorflow fine grained multithreading control

Tags: multithreading, tensorflow, keras

I have a small problem, where GPU or CPU multithreading does not give much speed. I also have a machine with many CPU threads (no GPU) and I would like to use them to train or tune many model variants on the problem in parallel, each variant using only one thread. How to do this?

Edit: Here are snippets of stuff I would like to do:

```py
from kerastuner.tuners import RandomSearch

tuner = RandomSearch(...)
tuner.search(...) # a machine with 128 CPU threads should search 128 models in parallel, training each with only one thread
```

```py
def fit_all(models, x, y):
    ...

fit_all(models, x, y) # a machine with 16 CPU threads should train 16 models in parallel, each using only one thread
```

Comment: do you want asynchronous training? You need to provide more details. If your models are running on GPU then you need more GPUs.

Comment: I edited my question, I just want CPU no GPU.

Comment: I am not sure of the precise meaning of "asynchronous training", but I believe the answer is yes.